# How to remove the gap between lopping an audio file Android

Tags: android, loops, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play an audio file for `x` number of times, and show the value of `x` to the user. My problem is i can use `mp.setLooping(true)` inorder to loop an audio without any gaps between looping, but i cant handle number of repetitions with it. So i used `OnCompletionListener` everything was just fine, but it produces a 1sec gap at the end or beginning of each repetition.

If i use `mp.setLooping(true)` the is no gap between looping.

If i use `OnCompletionListener` the a noticeable gap between looping.

The gap is produced only on Android 4.x.x and 3.x.x . How can i get rid of that gap ? Thanks in advance..

My code:

```
int n = 1;
int maxCount = 15; //This value changes according to user input.
private void mpplay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (n <= maxCount) {
                mp.start();
                n++;
                tv.setText("Counter:" + n);
                if (n >= maxCount) {
                    n = 1;
                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `n` and `maxCount` are declared globally.

Comment: Add Thread and Runnable Handler to play second audio file before some millisecond of first audio complete.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using two media players:

```
int n = 1;
int maxCount = 15; //This value changes according to user input.

MediaPlayer mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (n <= maxCount) {
                mp2.start();
                mp1.setDataSource(<File>);
                mp1.prepare();
                n++;
                tv.setText("Counter:" + n);
                if (n >= maxCount) {
                    n = 1;
                    mp2.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    });


MediaPlayer mp2 = new MediaPlayer();
mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (n <= maxCount) {
                mp1.start();
                mp2.setDataSource(<File>);
                mp2.prepare();
                n++;
                tv.setText("Counter:" + n);
                if (n >= maxCount) {
                    n = 1;
                    mp1.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    });

private void mpplay() {
    mp1.setDataSource(<File>);
    mp1.prepare();
    mp1.start();
}
```

Comment: There is still a gap between looping.

Comment: Are you targeting a specific API: 11, 13, etc? If the code only needs to run on 16+ then you can use setNextMediaPlayer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29